# Localizing in WPF

Tags: wpf, localization

I am localizing a WPF application. The datagrid columns headers needs to be changed at runtime according to the specific UI culture in the [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language).

Though I am able to do the localization in the code behind and also in XAML by using the [LocBaml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621.aspx) tool. I am not able to achieve it with one particular scenario in the XAML. The scenario is that I am parsing XAML, as I am loading it in an XML file and parsing..

So now when I parse it like:

```
<dg:DataGridColumnHeader Header="{x:Static findlocale:My.Resources.String.anylocalword}"></dg:DataGridColumnHeader>
```

Where findlocale is the XAML namespace keyword, I am getting an error:

> XAML parse error. Cannot find type `My.Resources.String.localword` in
>   the xaml namespace.

Why is this not working in this scenario? How do I overcome it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet your findlocale XML namespace is incorrect. If you have something like:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.MySubNamespace {
    public class MyClass {
        public static string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then your XML namespace must be declared like `xmlns:findlocale="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.MySubNamespace"` in order to use `{x:Static findlocale:MyClass.MyProperty}`.

You *cannot* declare your XML namespace like `xmlns:findlocale="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"` and use it like `{x:Static findlocale:MySubNamespace.MyClass.MyProperty}`.

Also, if you have any nested classes/enums, then you must use a `+` sign in place of the `.`. So if you had:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.MySubNamespace {
    public class MyClass {
        public class MyNestedClass {
            public static string MyProperty { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

To access `MyProperty`, you'd need to declare your XML namespace like `xmlns:findlocale="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.MySubNamespace"` and access it like `{x:Static findlocale:MyClass+MyNestedClass.MyProperty}`.